# Every class inherits Object class

Tags: java

In java, Object class is the super class for all classes. So suppose, if I inherit class B from A, i.e., A -> B, then is it not like multiple inheritance?

```
Object->A \
            B
   Object /
```

And multiple inheritance is not supported in Java, right?
So how is this possible? Will that not produce diamond dependency problem?

Apologies if the question is too naive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In [J]ava, `Object` class is the super class for all classes.

Your understanding of this statement is not correct. `Object` is the root of the hierarchy for any class, but it is *not* the **direct**<sup>1</sup> super class for all classes. In fact, `Object` is only the direct super class for classes that are explicitly derived from `Object` or do not explicitly list another super class. Otherwise, it sits higher up the hierarchy chain. So, every class (except `Object`) has one and only one direct super class, and that super class is either `Object` or some other class but if you work your way up a class' inheritance chain eventually you'll hit `Object` (which is what we mean by `Object` is a super class for every class).

> So suppose, if I inherit class `B` from `A`, i.e., `A` -> `B`, then is it not like multiple inheritance?

Then in this case the hierarchy is `B` derives from `A` derives from `Object`. The hierarchy is **not** `A` derives from `Object` and `B` derives from `A` and from `Object`. However, `Object` is the root of `B`'s hierarchy, as it is the root of the hierarchy for *any* class.

> And multiple inheritance is not supported in Java, right?

Correct.

> So how is this possible?

Your question is based on a false understanding. Again, `Object` is *not* the **direct** super class of every class. Multiple inheritance means more than one direct super class, and that is strictly forbidden in Java, yet consistent with `Object` being a super class (but not necessarily a **direct** super class) for every class.

<sup>1</sup>: Some people also use the term "immediate" for the direct super class of any class. The Java documentation uses "direct", so we will use that term here.

Answer (score 1):

Nop, is the transitivity property

`B extends A extends Object`
Only single inheritance involves.

It may confuse you cause

> (B is an A) (A is an Object) then (B is An Object).

So it's true that B is an Object , but is an object cause A is an Object. Supposing A not an Object then B not gonna to be an Object.

Answer (score 0):

The image is wrong. Class B inherits from A which inherits from Object. No multiple inheritance involved.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is not a direct superclass of all other classes; it is their *ultimate ancestor* class. This is the picture you are looking for.

```
                             Object
                            /     
                           A      
                          /
                         B
```

As you can see, it's a tree and no diamond problem can occur with a tree.